# C# - Remote Connection to XAMPP-Database via LAN

Tags: c#, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, lan

I have a database hosted with XAMPP on a PC with IP: 10.35.250.195

I want to access this database from a laptop in the same LAN where my C#-Application is running on.
This is my connection-string:

```
"SERVER=10.35.250.195;DATABASE=testdb;USERID=root;PASSWORD=;"
```

But I'm being unable to open a connection from a remote pc/laptop.

I can access the database with the above connection-string from the PC where the database is hosted. I can also access the phpmyadmin in the browser from the remote laptop with "10.35.250.195/phpmyadmin". So the connection works from the laptop to the PC with the database, but I am not able to open this remote connection in C#.

Within phpmyadmin I allowed user "root" to access host 10.35.250.195 with all rights and I even allowed that every user can access host 10.35.250.195 with all rights to get sure (I know I should not do this because of security reasons...).

How can I access the database in c# with mysql from a remote PC via Lan? Can somebody help me to find the fault?

Comment: See mysql manual section 5.4.  Using Windows credentials should allow remote connection without additional passwords : https://downloads.mysql.com/docs/connector-net-en.pdf.  See also https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/.  Sample connection string : Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;IntegratedSecurity=yes;
Uid=auth_windows;

Comment: The problem ist not how to open a connection in C# on windows. I am able to open the connection on the host-pc with the above mentioned connection-string. The problem is that it doesn't work from the remote-pc wiht that string.

Comment: Yes it is.  A PC doesn't allow remote PC connections unless the remote PC and Local PC are in the same group.  Then the user must have an account on both PCs.  So using IntegratedSecurit‌​y=yes; automatically uses the User windows login (and group account) instead of using a Username and Password.  So you have to setup a group account and add both local and PC to group.  Then add users to the group.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your port of the DB is blocked by a firewall?

MySql has Port: 3306

and you could also try a PC based tool to test it like 
https://www.heidisql.com/

Comment: According to "netstat" on the Host-PC the port :3306 is in state "Listening".

Comment: You should check your client but @jdweng has a good point. Try to connect with some database browser like Heidi, there you can test your settings and be sure not to have some code issues.