# C# XAMPP Connection

Tags: c#

I have followed this tutorial - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2g4MPJ3fJt0 - Only inserting it as for anyone who is looking to connect to XAMPP with C#, this is a great tutorial.

However,
When I try and replicate the connection variable I seem to get an error.... (beginning to think it's not the best tutorial - joke)

```
connString = "Data Source =127.0.0.0.1;Port =3306;User ID=root;Password=;Database=aa";
```

(Local host)

I get a keyword not support 'port' error.
I can't find any information online that is related to Windows Forms, all seems to be for .NET development.

Can someone post the formatting for XAMPP connection for WPF (if it has been updated) or inform how to import Port into the SqlConncetion syntax

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46406777/c-sharp-remote-connection-to-xampp-database-via-lan) might be helpful

Comment: Have you tried with no spaces?, the tutorial is using "datasource=127.0.0.1;port=3306;username=root;password=;database=test;", no spaces

Comment: What SQL connector are you using? Can you post more of your connection code?

Comment: The other problem is that you have too many zero's in your IP address, `127.0.0.0.1` is not a valid IP, should be `127.0.0.1`, that might fix the problem...

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial is using XAMPP just to install the database for you, at the end of the day your problem is between MySQL and your C# code.
You are using a connection string with spaces

> connString = "Data Source =127.0.0.0.1;Port =3306;User ID=root;Password=;Database=aa";

However the tutorial uses no spaces:

> connString = "datasource=127.0.0.1;port=3306;username=root;password=;database=test;";

It could help if you check your connection to your mysql database, you can download Mysql workbench and try to connect from there, so you can be sure if your database is well configured or not

Comment: Should have mentioned I guess but I followed the tutorial and originally had the exact code from the video. I changed it to 'Data Source' and 'User Id' to try and fix errors. When I use the code without the spaces, I still receive the same error about the 'port'. I am using phpmyadmin currently.

Comment: Are you able to connect with some client like workbench or datagrip?

Comment: @RonBeyer you are right, it is also wrong, i did not notice. But I do not know if the wrong ip address could cause the error he is mentioning "keyword not support 'port' error"